# gpflow model prediction says input was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor

Tags: tensorflow, double, gaussian, tensor, gpflow

I am trying to run the code from the gpflow tutorial:
https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/regression.html
However, it doesn't work.

The following code:

```
N = 12
X = np.random.rand(N,1)
Y = np.sin(12*X) + 0.66*np.cos(25*X) + np.random.randn(N,1)*0.1 + 3
plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)

k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(variance=1.0, lengthscale=1.0)
m = gpflow.models.GPR((X, Y), k, mean_function=None, noise_variance=1.0)
m.likelihood.variance = 0.01

def plot(m):
    xx = np.linspace(-0.2, 1.2, 141)[:,None]
    xx=tf.convert_to_tensor(xx,dtype=tf.float64)
    mean, var = m.predict_y(xx)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)
    plt.plot(xx, mean, 'b', lw=2)
    plt.fill_between(xx[:,0], mean[:,0] - 2*np.sqrt(var[:,0]), mean[:,0] + 2*np.sqrt(var[:,0]), color='blue', alpha=0.2)
    plt.xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
plot(m)
```

returns the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute AddV2 as input #1(zero-based) was
>   expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:AddV2] name:
>   add/

I have windows 10, python 3.6, tensorflow 2.0, tensorflow probability 0.9,
and gpflow was installed with
pip install -e .
command on 21st of february 2020.

Could you help me with this?
I do transform the input to double so I think it could be that gpflow updated
the code but not the tutorial.

Comment: Note that the up-to-date version of the tutorial is on https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ - unfortunately readthedocs is still serving a hugely out of date version under /stable/, which appears to be indexed by Google.

Comment: I wonder how did you make the plt.plot(xx, mean, 'b', lw=2) work? I get thrown 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim' error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you encounter is due to new way we update parameter values in GPflow. Instead of doing `model.parameter = value` you should use `assign`:

```
m.likelihood.variance.assign(0.01)
```

This makes sure the type of the parameters is not changed.

I was able to get the following plot, after setting the `lengthscale` of the kernel to `0.25`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked (and answered myself) the very same question here: [GPFlow-2.0 - issue with default_float and likelihood variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055919)

In general, I would suggest NOT using the examples on readthedocs if you're trying to use gpflow 2.0.  Instead, clone the github repository and use the example notebooks from there - these have mostly been updated to work correctly with gpflow 2.

For example, the updated version of your regression example is available here: https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/basics/regression.pct.py

This version works with gpflow 2.

Comment: The issue isn't with the docs itself - the [latest readthedocs for the develop branch](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) are working just fine - but that readthedocs has a stale cache of old versions that are still indexed by google. There's an [open issue for that](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/1297) but I don't know what we can do to get rid of the stale version!

Comment: It's a bit of both - the "current release" of gpflow is 1.5.1 and google points at the docs for that version.  Version 2.0 of gpflow is still being developed and hasn't been officially released.  At the same time, very few will install the released version of gpflow these days given its dependencies are quite stale (tensorflow 1.x) but everyone will trust google for finding examples of how to use it.

You more or less have to clone the git repository to install gpflow 2 anyway, and the example notebooks come with the repo .